# Laravel/PHP - the right choice for running jobs in parallel?

Tags: php, laravel

My current application holds the status of round about 5000 network nodes in a database. Each node should get updated minutely to provide the current status. Updating process looks like the following:

1. Get old entry from database to get its IP
2. Send a RPC to the node
3. Update database entry with returned data

For this I'm running Laravel horizon that provides me a neat job scheduler based on redis. Every minute a cron gets all node-entries and pushs each `UpdateNode(id)` task to the scheduler.

With number of nodes increasing I have to constantly increase the schedule workers as well. Currently 60 PHP threads are only responsible for updating nodes to keep the minutely update-circle running.

That fact again leads to a huge ressource problem (currently 80% RAM and 70% CPU on a 40$ DigitalOcean Droplet) which leads me again to my main questions:

1. Is Laravel (or much more PHP) still the right candidate for this job?
2. Am I maybe doing something wrong from a Laravel-perspective? Normaly getting a DB-Entry, sending an RPC and update the entry with new data should be no big deal.

//edit: Here is my `iostat`:
[image]

//for all who are interested here is the project: https://github.com/nknx-org/nknx-api
The job we're talking about is https://github.com/nknx-org/nknx-api/blob/master/app/Jobs/UpdateNode.php

Comment: post please `iostat`

Comment: Are the nodes capable of pushing updates rather than being polled?

Comment: Without looking at your code or resources utilization stats it's hard to give you an answer; anyway you may be able to eliminate the first step by storing the old ip along with the job to process it should lower the time required to process the jobs by a fraction.

Comment: @TravisBritz Sadly no - would be easier, yes  :)

Comment: @FAEWZX did that - If some code is helpful I can provide that as well but I thought first to ask a general question about that situation

Comment: Is it possible to change requirements a bit? Maybe lower the frequency to 2 minutes thus you can check-status of all nodes in 2 minutes (1st half the first minute, 2nd half the second minute). It would be nice to know what you are doing with the data; are you writing new records or just updating? Maybe use cache instead of saving to the DB right away and once in a while save the cached results for persistence. Does it matter if some nodes are "out of date" for more than x minutes? Also are you using `php artisan queue:work --once` or `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: @Kyslik sadly no, nodes have to be updated every minute. Laravel horizon runs the jobs by default with:
``horizon:work redis --delay=0 --memory=128 --queue=default --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=3 --supervisor=SUPERVISORHERE``

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is split up the work of dispatching jobs into yet another job, if the scheduled task is any kind of bottleneck.

Instead of having your single scheduled task responsible for dispatching all 5000 `UpdateNode` jobs for the workers, you could split the records into chunks of ids. So your scheduled task would split the 5000 records into chunks of 250 ids for example, and dispatch 20 new `DispatchUpdateNodeJobs($ids)` jobs each with an array of 250 ids.

These jobs goes onto your normal queue system for your workers to pick up, and each worker that picks up a `DispatchUpdateNodeJobs` job in turn dispatches its 250 `UpdateNode` jobs when it runs, and then those jobs get picked up by the workers as they do now. This might make it easier to scale out the work depending on how your system is set up, as well as potentially get the full 5000 jobs onto the queue for the workers more quickly if your scheduled task was taking a long time to create 5000 jobs.

However, If you're saying the cpu usage is high because all 60 of your existing workers are on the *same server*, then I think you just need to add another server to split up the work. 60 PHP processes each using 1% CPU and ~25mb of memory would still total 60% CPU and 1.5gb of memory used, there's no way to avoid that with so many active processes.

If the database is on the same system and is also using a lot of cpu, then you might also need to optimize queries, add indexes, and other performance tuning for your use case. The fastest database. is one you don't access (take advantage of things you can cache).

Ultimately the best option will depend on what your current bottlenecks are and how the system is set up.

Comment: That's actually a good strategy. Sadly every RPC-call has a maximal timeout of 1 sec so that I can only do 60 jobs in batch but that would help. Also adding another server would be a possibility. My server specs are:

- 8GB RAM
- 4 vCPUs

It's just strange that the 60 processes fill up the server so consistent, I also added the repository in the starting post!

Indexes are added in the database.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood? The chunking is just to *dispatch* the individual `UpdateNode` tasks; nothing changes with regard to running them so the RPC timeout would behave as it did before. The advantage is that you don't have a single scheduled command running for a long time dispatching all 5000 jobs to the queue

Comment: Oh yeah, I did misunderstood the concept - now I understand that you're suggesting not to optimize the ``UpdateNode`` job itself - instead the dispatching is a kind of bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

%user = 53% 
it one task = 1% * 4CPU = 4% it is Big

Split you task

`handle()` - only get data to folder or redis

```
file_put_contents("/path/to/response/nodes/".time()."_".$node->alias,$apiRequest->getBody());
```

Push All json to database from folder Every minute in One task.